# Scheduling a slow query

Tags: t-sql

I have a query which runs via cursors and it is slow because it monitors lots of fields.

I would like to run this query automatically every week. it takes around 2 minutes. so do you think a job scheduling? or a query to send an email will do? or do you have any other options??? Thank you!!!

In the below query it checks only for L_name but I have 50 more fields like that.

```
SELECT 
a.invnumber, a.Accnum,
i.audit_field, i.field_after, name, i.maxdate AS Modified_date
FROM 
#Iam a
JOIN 
(SELECT
     a.invnumber, a.Accnum, a.field_after, audit_field, maxdate
 FROM
     #Iam_audit a WITH(nolock)
 INNER JOIN
     (SELECT 
          Accnum, invnumber, MAX(Modified_Date) AS maxdate
      FROM
          #Iam_audit a2 WITH(nolock)
      WHERE
          a2.Audit_field = 'name'
      GROUP BY
          Accnum, invnumber) AS aa ON aa.Accnum = a.Accnum 
                                   AND aa.invnumber = a.invnumber 
                                   AND aa.maxdate = a.modified_Date
WHERE
    a.Audit_Field = 'name') i ON i.audit_field = 'name'  
                              AND i.Accnum = a.Accnum 
                              AND i.invnumber = a.invnumber  
                              AND a.name <> i.field_after
```

Comment: 2 minutes isn't that big of a deal really. So, sure, I think scheduling it would be fine

Comment: Although, I would suggest if there is slight chance of improvement of code then think in that direction. Could you please confirm SQL SERVER version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server, then scheduling a job using the SQL Agent would definitely be the way to go.
As stated in the comments, 2 minutes is not a very long time for the query. Simply schedule the job for a time when the system is not under heavy use.

But if you want to move to the more modern implementation of SQL I would look to implement set-based data operations rather than cursors. This may or may not improve the query timings, but is something I would definitely look at doing for a production server.

Cursors are generally looked down upon for production operations, although, you may be able to justify them in some cases.

Comment: Thank you. I guess yeah. I will go with jobs then! You are right..cursors is not the best to use.. but for dynamic queries, its good!